# Images not displaying in Phone Gap app

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am fairly new to Phone Gap. I have a clear understanding of HTML and jQuery. What seems to be very simple in HTML doesn't turn out be so simple when using it in Phone Gap.

Currently I am testing it on a Android device.

I am trying to display images, the images are being pulled from a server.

**Output HTML**

```
<h3>The Bass Angler</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Price: </strong>R35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img  style="width: 50%; height: 50%" src="http://www.adventurebuddy.co.za/uploads/cover.PNG" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
function ViewMag(id)
{
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("select magid,name,price from mag where magid =  " + id + " order by name", [], 
       function(tx, rs){
          html = '<br /><h3>' + rs.rows.item(0).name + '</h3>';
          html += '<table><tr><td><strong>Price: </strong>R' + rs.rows.item(0).price + '</td></tr>'

          // Load editions for a magazine
          db.transaction(function(tx1){
              tx1.executeSql("select editionid,editiondate,filepath,cover from editions where deleted is null and magid = " + id, [], 
                  function(tx1,rs1){
                      if(rs1.rows.length == 0)
                          html += '<p>No editions found.</p>';
                      else
                      {               
                          //html += '<ul class="">';
                          for(ri1=0;ri1<rs1.rows.length;ri1++)
                          {
                              var coverurl = APPSERVER + '/uploads/' + rs1.rows.item(ri1).cover;
                              var file = APPSERVER + '/uploads/' + rs1.rows.item(ri1).filepath 

                              html += '<tr><td><img  style="width: 50%; height: 50%" src="' + coverurl + '" /></td></tr>'
                          }               
                          html += '</table>';
                      }
                  });
          });

          $.ui.updatePanel('#main',html);
          $.ui.setTitle(rs.rows.item(0).name);
          $.ui.loadContent('#main',false,false,"right");               
       }, 
       window.onDBError
    );
});
```

If I save the HTML code as a htm file it works fine but doesn't work on the phone. What am I missing?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

The variable *html* was out of scope inside the function *db.transaction()*. I had to restructure my function and end up moving out some code into a new function

**jQuery**

```
function ViewEditions(id){
    $.ui.loadContent('#editions',false,false,"right");
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql("select editionid,editiondate,filepath,cover from editions where deleted is null and magid = " + id, [], 
            function(tx,rs){
                if(rs.rows.length == 0)
                    html = '<p>No editions found.</p>';
                else {               
                    html = '<ul class="list">';
                    for(ri=0;ri<rs.rows.length;ri++)
                    {
                        var coverurl = APPSERVER + '/uploads/' + rs.rows.item(ri).cover;
                        var file = APPSERVER + '/uploads/' + rs.rows.item(ri).filepath 
                        html += '<li><a href="#" onclick="downloadFile(' + file + ',' + rs.rows.item(ri).filepath + ');"><img  style="width: 50%; height: 50%" src="' + coverurl + '" /><div align="left">' + rs.rows.item(ri).editiondate + '</div></a></li>'; 

                    }               
                    html += '</ul>';
                }

            $('#editionsresults').html(html); 
        },window.onDBError
        );
    });

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to whitelist the domain. Have a read [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html).

What that says is that you need to add

```
<access origin="http://www.adventurebuddy.co.za" />
```

to the `config.xml` file in order to tell PhoneGap that it's not a red signal of a trojan trying to access random URLs

> EDIT: for the OP to use a 'hack'.

Now, you can assign the `img` element an `id`.

```
<img  style="width: 50%; height: 50%" id="image" />
```

then, from your JavaScript (with jQuery), you can do something like:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://www.adventurebuddy.co.za/uploads/cover.PNG',
    type: "GET", 
    success: function( data ) {
        var f = $( "#image" ).attr( "src", data ); 
        console.log(f); // just to check it.
    },
    error: function( xhr, status, thrownErorr ) {
        console.log( xhr + "\r\n" + status + "\r\n" + thrownError );
    }
 });
```

If this doesn't work, it means that your phone is **preventing** requests to that URL and you need to get into the **device logs**.

Comment: This is in the config.xml <access origin="*" />

Comment: I also see that the whitelist plugin is included in the config file

Comment: Any specific error it gives when you try it on your phone?

Comment: I tested that code and it seems to get the image so that eliminate that possibility

Comment: According to some sources, that seems impossible to do. That hack is the best we can do. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95043/discussion-between-weirdpanda-and-gericke).